# Floated div jumps down in a fluid layout at certain window widths

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with a fluid layout. It works fine mostly, but at certain window widths,  one of four floating div-elements jumps down. This occurs at nearly 20 different widths, and only at one pixel. For example, it looks weird at 346px but not at 347px.

There are two rows with two elements side by side. The first two always work, but the last element on the second row is the one jumping down.

There are no margin issues - I have tried setting the width of the floated divs to 40% but even then, the behaviour is still the same.

I don't use `clear` anywhere either. I only use paddings with the CSS3 `box-sizing`-property, to avoid this problem, and also because I want to use em in the paddings.

There are four `recipe-teaser`; I only include one since the code is exactly the same.

```
<div id="recipe-gateway">
    <h1>Veckans recept</h1>

    <div class="recipe-teaser">

        <h2 class="recipe-teaser-headline"><a href="#">Potatissoppa</a></h2>
        <a href="#"><img class="recipe-teaser-img" src="potatissoppa.jpg" alt="Potatissoppa" /></a>
        <div class="time"><p>20 min</p></div>

        <div class="recipe-teaser-link">
            <a href="#" class="related-link">Till receptet</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.recipe-teaser {
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0.825em 0 0.825em;
 }
```

The parent element:

```
#recipe-gateway {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0 -0.625em -0.625em -0.625em;
    padding: 0 0 1.25em 0;
}
```

And #recipe-gateway's parent:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1% 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The container:

```
#container {
width:100%;
padding: 1%;
background-color:#727D07;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

This behavious occurs in the latest version of Chrome. 
In FireFox, the last element is always jumped down.

Comment: Have you tried using a clear after the first row?

Comment: Also, can you please make a jsFiddle of your codes

Comment: @mizuki I made this fiddle based on your code but I can't replicate the problem. Can you make one or post a link to your site? http://jsfiddle.net/hN3KY/

Comment: Andy: Yep, and it din't work. :/

Comment: wf4: Link to page: http://burningwest.com/Sasongssmart/index.html. 
It's a responsive site - the problem occurs between 320px-611px window width.

Comment: (It's for a school assignment, so it's a bit dorky...)

Comment: Just to point you in the right direction; removing the border from `#recipe-gateway` fixes the layout

Comment: 3rror404: Oh no, I really need the border. I wonder why it works, since I have used box-sizing on all the divs?

Comment: @mizuko clearing on the 3rd `recipe-teaser`... so `<div class="recipe-teaser" style="clear: left;">` will fix this for you but I'm puzzled why the 3rd is not falling to the left. I'll keep looking at this for you unless someone else can help out with this one.

Comment: @wf4: Thanks a lot!! I have been confused over this for two days now, it's so weird, even my teacher in web design/programming can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Strangely, it the original image was 639px instead of 600px wide. All the images were resized in the CSS, but since it was an uneven number, that may have caused problems.